# Google drive disconnect from COLAB

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am working on neural networks in Keras and I use Colab to train my network. Unfortunately, any time I stop the training, one of the following problems occurs:

- Colab unmounts my gdrive folder. So I must remount it to restart the training.
- My gdrive folder on Colab partially empties (I loose my dataset). In this case I also need to restart the session in order to remount gdrive.

Does anyone know the reasons ?

Comment: are you mounting the google drive and running the training in same cell?

Comment: I mount gdrive in a separated cell.

Answer (score 0):

By stopping the training, do you mean stopping the kernel?
If you stop or restart the kernel, the drive will be unmounted.
If you want your training to continue, save your models into checkpoints.

Comment: By stopping training I just meant stopping the fit_generator method. I use checkpoints and I can see they do their job, however I cannot load a saved model cause colab disconnects the gdrive folder.